# How to use pagination for filtered query in angular 6 and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination

I have huge records in mongo collection. I need to display 5 records at a time in front end. So Im sending only 5 records and total count from the nodejs server. In UI Im displaying those 5 records and on click of next , sending the next 5 records. As of now I have id which was auto increment field from mongo, so using that im fetching the next or previous records by incrementing or decrementing 5 from the id(numeric auto increment).

Instead of fetching all records and limiting, Im querying by id for optimizing performance. But now the problem comes when I need to filter the data. I should filter by any of the field where id order might change. so here how should i implement pagination ?

My current query in nodejs:

```
query = { Class: { $in: ["GF"] }, Id_num: { $gt: From , $lte: To} }
```

Here From is where I would pass the ids 1 to 5 for initial level, then on click of next 6 to 10 and so on. But now if I filter the values can be ,

```
    3,6,8,17,20,21 or anything.
```

Now how should i implement pagination. Should I query the entire collection with sorting each time ? Is there any other way. Kindly suggest.

Comment: The pagination logic can remain the same using `_id`, you just need to add a sort on the `_id` field when filtering with other fields.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert If I retrieve first 5 records after filtering the ids would be like ( 3,6,8,17,20 ) , So i want to retrieve next 5 records, without filter id would be continuous, so i will add 5 and query, but here ids are continuous know. Could you please let me know how it is possible?

Comment: in the case there is a filter you could just use the 20 instead of the 5. the logic remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the backend..
you can use Skip and Limit for page navigation. i.e., pagination

```
const page = req.query.page * 1 || 1;
const limit = req.query.limit * 1 || 10;
const skip = (page - 1) * limit;
```

Then in the Query,

```
await User.find({})
          .sort({ score: -1 })
          .skip(skip).limit(limit);
```

Then in your Query

```
{{URL}}/User?page=1&limit=10
```